# \pdfbookmark hyperlink aims to low with \includepdf

Tags: bookmarks, pdfpages

I'm trying to use pdfTeX to bring together several PDF documents and use the bookmarks feature of Adobe/Preview to supply a hyperlinking structure in a sidebar window. When I try this with multiple PDF files at multiple levels of indentation, the hyperlinking structure "works", but some of the links aim too low! Check out the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\usepackage{pdfpages}%
\usepackage{bookmark}%

\begin{document}%
\pdfbookmark[1]{Test 0}{test0}%
\includepdf[pages={-},link,linkname=test0,linkfit=FitH]{Testpdf0.pdf}%

\pdfbookmark[2]{Test 1}{test1}%
\includepdf[pages={-},link,linkname=test1,linkfit=FitH]{Testpdf1.pdf}%

\pdfbookmark[3]{Test 2}{test2}%
\includepdf[pages={-},link,linkname=test2,linkfit=FitH]{Testpdf2.pdf}%

\pdfbookmark[1]{Test 3}{test3}%
\includepdf[pages={-},link,linkname=test3,linkfit=FitH]{Testpdf3.pdf}%
\end{document}%
```

Use your favorite PDF files for Testpdf files 0, 1, 2 and 3. Compile this and then open the resulting document in either Adobe Reader or Preview and click on the bookmarks. The bookmarks for Test 0 and Test 3 work fine -- you can see the top 1.5 cm of your document -- which is what I want. However the bookmarks Test 1 and Test 2 aim too low cutting off the top of each of these pages. Any ideas how to fix this behavior? (Is it intentional?)

I'm preparing an important document and I do not want to annoy my reader (or they won't be incline to decide in my favor)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should fix it, although I'm not sure whether it would break other things.

Add

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\pdfbookmark}[3][0]{%
  \bookmark[level=#1,dest={#3.1}]{#2}% originally dest={#3.#1}
  \hyper@anchorstart{#3.1}\hyper@anchorend% originally #3.#1
}
\makeatother
```

to your document preamble after loading [`bookmark`](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark). The above modification fixes the destination of the hyper target to `#3.1` (level 1), while the bookmark level is still dependent on the first (optional argument) and internally set using `level=#1`.

This is most certainly intended. Level 1 (and 0) bookmarks typically form part of full-page styles (like a `\chapter` or `\part`), while lower-level bookmarks occur in the middle of the page (like `\section` and `\subsection`). To see why this is the case, include the [`showframe` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/showframe) in your preamble. The hyperlinks from the bookmarks at levels 2 and 3 just to the first line of the text block, indicated by the border made by `showframe`.

Answer (score 1):

`\pdfbookmark` hyperlink seem to aim to the top of the printable area.

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{top=0cm}
```

solved it for me.